# Difference between "May" and "Let" in biblical language

Tags: meaning

Is there a meaning difference between “May” and “Let” in the following examples?

1. May/Let praise be to the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ.
2. May/Let thanks be to God.
3. May/Let the God (and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ) be blessed.

Comment: I think this is better asked on [hermeneutics.se]. Remember that the Bible was translated from Aramaic (and Greek etc) so all words are attempts at capturing concepts from other languages, and there may be no perfect English word which captures the specific idea of the word in the original language.

Comment: Where have you seen these renderings?  "Let" seems unusual to my liturgical ear, but I think an argument over the choice of Let/May could easily slide into theology.  I'm not sure I agree with @DanBron that the question belongs in a Biblical forum, but it would be helpful if we could see this in a more strictly "English usage" framework.

Comment: @Rob_Ster So, "May the Force be with you," or "Let the Force be with you."? ;-)

Comment: @Mick - Indeed..."May" seems to imply a wishful benediction, while "Let" feels more imperative?  "Let" feels like "fiat" - "Let there be light," etc

Comment: Are these actual Biblical quotations, because I'm having difficulty finding them? It would help to give references and explain what version of the Bible they're from.

Answer (score 1):

For each of your examples, the better word of the two is *may*, in my opinion.

*Let* and *may* seem similar in meaning (and to some extent, they are), but they are used in slightly different ways.

In the context of biblical content, *let* brings to my mind the old-fashioned use of the word *let*, which implied that a hindrance or obstacle must be removed. A common phrase in "legalese" is: "without let or hindrance" (meaning *obstacle*).

Therefore, when *let* appears in a biblical text, it *can* mean to allow, implying there should be no obstacle, as in the words of Jesus:

> Let not your heart be troubled. Ye believe in God; believe also in me (John 14:1).

In other words,

> Do not allow your heart to be troubled . . ..

Or,

> Allow your heart to be *un*-troubled . . ..

On the other hand, in biblical content, the word *may* does not carry with it the idea of an obstacle; rather, it implies there *is no* obstacle, so

> This is how it ought to be, or this is how it should happen . . ..

So instead of saying

> May praise be to the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ,

you could say

> This is what should happen: Praise [should be] to the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ.

As Rob Ster, above, aptly said, "*May* seems to imply a wishful benediction, while *let* . . . feels like 'fiat,' [as in] 'Let there be light.'"

Comment: The notion that _may_ is ‘correct’ and _let_ is ‘incorrect’ in these cases is not really borne out by the rest of the answer, or indeed, I would say, by reality. “Let praise be to God” is not common, but nor is “May praise be to God”. Both versions yield only a handful of hits on Google (_let_ actually yields a few more than _may_). The more common version is just “Praise be to God”, which also gives over half a million Google hits. I would suggest you remove the first sentence in the answer entirely.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Can't do it; wouldn't be prudent. In the NASV (New American Standard Version of the Bible), the word "may" appears some 318 times. I'm not suggesting that EVERY appearance of the word takes the meaning in the sense that I've explained in my answer, but many do. For example: 1 Peter 1:2 & 7; 4:11; Ephesians 1:17-18; 3:17-19; 6:19-20; 1 Thessalonians 3:11-13; Romans 15:5; 2 Thessalonians 2:16; 3:16; and more. The OP, I surmise, is more interested in how the words "may" and "let" are used in the Bible and not in everyday sorts of speaking and writing.

Comment: It’s not prudent either to mislead people into thinking that “May praise be to God” is ‘correct’, because it is in fact **not** used anywhere in the Bible. I’m not talking about how _may_ and _let_ are used in general in the Bible; but you specifically say that _may_ is the **correct** word for **each** of the examples in the question, and that is incorrect. For the first example, at least, neither _let_ nor _may_ is ‘correct’ (as in used in the Bible or used in normal speech).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: No need to yell. I'll concede that a better first sentence in my answer is in order. I will not concede, however, that the concept/idea/sentiment of "may God be praised" is somehow not biblical. See, for example, Psalm 106:58 in the HCSB version, which reads,  "May Yahweh, the God of Israel, be praised from everlasting to everlasting. Let all the people say, 'Amen! Hallelujah!'"

Comment: This question, and the discussion, is not about concepts/ideas/sentiments, but about words.

Comment: @rhetorician I wasn’t yelling, just using bold for emphasis (because I use italics for use-mention). Your edited version is much better and not misleading. Note, though, that “May God be praised” (perfectly common and normal, both in and out of the Bible) is a different construction to “May praise be to God”. The concept is the same, but the grammar is different.

Comment: @ColinFine: Concepts/ideas/sentiments do not exist without words. Where there are words, there are meanings; where there are meanings, there are ideas/concepts/sentiments. Don

Comment: @rhetorician: your first point (that those things do not exist without words) is debatable. Your second point is irrelevant. Read my point as "This question, and the discussion, is not about **differences between** concepts/ideas/sentiments, but about **differences between** words".

Comment: 'In the Bible' is almost as nebulous as 'in the dictionary'. Many contemporary versions omit the 'magic may' from I Pet 1:2, and CEV even shows Peter assuming some responsibility. JL has commented about certain English constructions that their analysis seems indeterminate, and the divine grace .. responsibility (predestination .. free will) coexistence also seems 'fractal as far as man can see'.